# How can I get a specific value from a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `.df` that looks something like this(`df = pandas.read_csv(main_db)`):

| itemName | itemBrand | itemCode | itemStock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| some name | some brand | a 6 digit number | some low number |
| even more names | even more brands | nore 6-digit numbers | more stocks |

Looks like that but with actual names and brands.

Now if I use `result = df[df['itemCode']==itemCode]`, I get:

| blank | itemName | itemBrand | itemCode | itemStock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | itemname7 | itembrand7 | 905616 | 13 |

It's very good. I spend too damn long looking for this. Now, I'm looking to get only the `itemStock` (In this case 13) to use somewhere else. So here I use `result2 = result['itemStock']`.

| 6 | 13 |
| --- | --- |

`Name: itemStock, dtype: int64`

Hm. okay, not what I wanted. What can I do to get only `13`?

Comment: you have requested a series, `result['itemStock'].values` or `result['itemStock'].values[0]`

Comment: ```int(result['itemStock'].values)``` will do also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use:

```
result2 = result['itemStock']
```

it returns you a data series so you see also the index and not only the value you want. You can check it using

```
type(result2)
```

You can find what you want using .values attribute

```
result2 = result['itemStock'].values
```

Comment: Thanks! Used `result2 = str(result['itemStock'].values)` and `print(result2.strip("[]"))` and it worked flawlessly!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
result = df.loc[(['itemCode']==itemCode, 'itemStock')].iat[0]
```

or just iat[0] on your 2nd result